# What is the meaning of "what it is" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "what it is"  in the following sentence,

> "Carrier mobility is about half of **what it is** for n channels"

?

( Source: [https://course.ece.cmu.edu/~ee321/spring99/LECT/lect20apr2.pdf](https://course.ece.cmu.edu/%7Eee321/spring99/LECT/lect20apr2.pdf)  )

Does "what it is" mean "carrier mobility" ?

Does "Carrier mobility is about half of what it is for n channels" mean "Carrier mobility is about half of carrier mobility for n channels" ?

I don't understand what "what it is" refers to in the sentence. I would appreciate it if you could explain with a few easy examples.

Comment: It's unclear without the context. Please [edit] your question and (1) tell us where you found this material (Is it a slideshow in an electronics class at a university??), (2) tell us what this sentence is about (Is it describing an electronic circuit or component??), and (3) give us the background knowledge necessary to understand what the technical terms refer to, like "carrier mobility", "n" and "channels".

Comment: gotube//  3) A carrier refers to a charged electron, proton, or ion that can move when an electric field is applied. A channel refers to an area where an environment for carriers to easily move is created by applying an electric field to the semiconductor environment where it is difficult for carriers to move. The n-channel and p-channel refer to individual channels formed in environments with slightly different semiconductor characteristics.

Comment: 1) where I found this material  : 
( Source: https://course.ece.cmu.edu/~ee321/spring99/LECT/lect20apr2.pdf )

Comment: 2) This is about the properties of a semiconductor called a transistor, especially a transistor called a MOSFET, which controls the semiconductor by applying an electric field.

Comment: Great work on (2) and (3). For (1) please tell us what that document is. For instance, is it "*a slide show for a university course on electrical circuits or components*", or something else? Just the link isn't enough. Also, please [edit] all of this into your original question above; don't just leave it in the comments. Thanks

Comment: And FWIW, use the @ symbol before a username to tag someone, like: @gotube

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole sentence likely refers to the level of carrier mobility in p-channel transistors, saying it is much less than the carrier mobility in n-channel transistors.

Consider other comparisons:
*The mass of a car is far less than what it is for a large truck.*

*The complexity of an architectural project like a skyscraper is much greater than what it is for a house.*

"what it is" is a short relative clause.
Expanded, using the original example,
the mobility (for a p-channel) is less than *what it (the mobility) is for n-channels*.

The word "what" is a pronoun introducing the clause.

Comment: If so, does "The mass of a car is far less than what it is for a large truck" mean "The mass of a car is far less than the mass of a large truck for a large truck" ? does "what it is" mean "the mass of a large truck" ?  What does "what" mean  and what does "it" mean?

Comment: I tried to clarify my answer above. The word "what" introduces the clause. "it" refers to carrier mobility, and "what" heads the clause.

Comment: Actually, "what it is" is not a clause but an NP in a fused relative construction. It's the equivalent of the non-fused "that which it is".

Answer (score 1):

//Question: "Carrier mobility is about half **of what it is** for n channels"

Is it this?

"Carrier mobility is about half of carrier mobility for n channels"?//

Answer: YES

The reason they say "what it is" is **to avoid repeating the term "carrier mobility**".

- My allowance is half of what my sister's is.
  That means:
- My allowance is half of my sister's allowance.
  No repetition of the word allowance in the first one above.

Comment: Can I apply the structure of the example sentence provided ("My allowance is half of what my sister's is.") to the sentence used in the question? (( what my sister' s is ==> what n channels' carrier mobility is ))   If so, does "it" mean "n channels's carrier mobility" ? If so, does ""Carrier mobility is about half of what it is for n channels" mean "Carrier mobility is about half of what  n channels' carrier mobility is for n channels"?

Comment: If so, does "The mass of a car is far less than what it is for a large truck" mean "The mass of a car is far less than what a large truck' mass is for a large truck"?

Comment: @user175012 With all due respect, I explained the structure. Why are you asking me again?